# How to replace part of a string in a MariaDB Server Table Column

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I would like to replace part of the txt content from a MariaDB 10.5 database table with a different value.

Example:

Database: users
Table: humans
Column: area
values: as below

```
row 1: ["area1","area2","area 3","area 4","area6"]
row 2: ["area1"]
row 3: ["area1","area 5"]
```

I would like to replace `area1` too `area 01` from all entries

I was thinking something along the line of:

```sql
UPDATE humans
SET area = replace(area, 'area1', 'area 01')
WHERE area like '%area1%'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Sorry I am using MySQL and it is on MariaDB 10.518

Comment: It's pretty much NEVER a good a idea to put comma-separate data in a table column. Fix that (because this schema really is _broken_), and suddenly this becomes much easier.

Comment: Mariadb has https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_replace/  but you will have no fun with it

Comment: I edited to make it more clear that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are two different products with different implementations of JSON functions. MariaDB is not MySQL.

Comment: Did you try the update you show?  What happened?

Comment: Is humans the database or the table?  Is area the table or the column?  You seem confused about terminology

Comment: What is the logic behind having "area" and numbers with and without spaces between? Are there other strings than "area" in this column? If not, avoid redundancy.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was confused myself  updated the OP and adjusted database, table and column

Comment: Table humans hold data for a user that has used front end to subscribe to notifications that are based from a location. User can sub to different areas and these are stored in the database in the table humans. Where the area column is a string of multiple areas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `REGEXP_REPLACE` as follows

```
UPDATE humans
SET area = REGEXP_REPLACE(area, '"area[ ]*([0-9]+)"', '"area 0\\1"')
```

[see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2GJat9zB)